# How to set some property above after converting class to sting using toJson Method

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I doing serialization Gson().toJson(objOfClass). but I need to set **SEQ,& SRC property before the DEVAWSEP** so how could I set it?

```
{"state":{"desired":{"ACT":1,"DEVAWSEP":"xxxxxxxxx","SEQ":6048799,"SRC":"MA"}}}
```

I want this form

```
{"state":{"desired":{"ACT":1,"SEQ":6048799,"SRC":"MA","DEVAWSEP":"xxxxxxxxx"}}}
```

**so I want to do to serialization without alphabet order**

I m use this library.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

Comment: Show the class you're serializing

Comment: @m0skit0 Class Detail in screenshot
https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1880

Comment: I'm nosy why you wan't to do this, could you please explain? Every common json-deserializer should be able to parse a file no matter what order it's in?

Comment: @m.reiter yes, but we are working with an embedded system and they need this sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m achieve this by writing a manual JsonSerializer like this.

```
class DesiredSerializer : JsonSerializer<Desired> {
    override fun serialize(
        desired: Desired?,
        typeOfSrc: Type?,
        context: JsonSerializationContext?,
    ): JsonElement {
        var o: JsonObject = JsonObject()
        o.add("ACT", context?.serialize(desired?.ACT))
        return o
    }
 }
```